# Создание jar-пакета в GWT

Tags: jar, java, gwt

Не подскажете, как создать jar-пакет (GWT) для дальнейшего использования в другом проекте?

Comment: А чем использование gwt осложняет процесс создания джарника?

Comment: Получается, создание пакета в GWT и просто в Java процесс одинаковый?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Процесс не совсем одинаковый. Чтобы использовать jar в GWT, надо чтобы в этом jar'е были запакованы исходники. В противном случае, вы не сможете использовать такой jar для генерирования клиентского кода.

Comment: каким образом это сделать?